# How to get the goldenRatio using recursion in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on this simple java recursion problem given the following directions:

- Calculate the golden ratio.
- Given two numbers a and b with a > b > 0, the ratio is b / a.

I have done some code but I'm stuck on getting the recursion working properly. Here's my code:

```
public class MyTesting {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ratio(8 , 4));
}

public static double ratio(int a, int b) {

    int goldelRatio = 0;
    if(a > b && b > 0){
        return goldelRatio = a / b;
    }

    return goldelRatio;
}

}
```

Comment: just updated the title.

Comment: You are missing the recursion part. You have to call ratio from inside of ratio to have recursion.

Comment: @matt yes but how would that implemented?. I'm a little stuck on that

Comment: return ratio(b, a+b);

Comment: Your definition is off. Reverse `a` and `b` in your first line such that b > a > 0. Then the ratio is b / a. After that (c, d, e) it's all good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
double goldenRatio(double a, double b, double epsilon) {
    if(Math.abs((b / a) - ((a + b) / b)) < epsilon) {
        return ((a + b) / b);
    } else {
        return goldenRatio(b, a + b, epsilon);
    }
}
```

This way you achieve what you need in one function, with epsilon deciding how fine the resolution would be.

Also as an added bonus, and although Java doesn't have (at the time of writing this at least) tail recursion optimization, in theory this function could be optimized by tail recursion.

example with hard coded epsilon:

```
double goldenRatio(double a, double b) {
    double epsilon = 0.00001;
    if(Math.abs((b / a) - ((a + b) / b)) < epsilon) {
        return ((a + b) / b);
    } else {
        return goldenRatio(b, a + b);
    }
}
```

example run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double goldenRation1 = goldenRatio(1.0, 1.0);
    System.out.println(goldenRation1); // prints 1.618032786885246
    System.out.println(goldenRation1 > 1.61800 && goldenRation1 < 1.61806); // prints true

    double goldenRation2 = goldenRatio(100.0, 6.0);
    System.out.println(goldenRation2); // prints 1.6180367504835589
    System.out.println(goldenRation2 > 1.61800 && goldenRation2 < 1.61806); // prints true
}
```

Comment: then you could hard code epsilon. I'll edit to show an example. In general all recursion methods must have a stop condition, wither hard coded or provided in use. Otherwise they'd go on foreer and you'd probably get a `StackOverflow` *wink*

Comment: Im testing your answer but it doesnt work when I run it using my test method

Comment: @progx Try again, I forgot a `Math.abs` there.

Comment: Its still not working. I went ahead and added the method test to my question so you can see it and test it. I get a RunTimeException and not sure why

Comment: Please take a look at the Test Method I added. When I run it it doesnt work with your answer and I get a RunTimeExeption

Comment: I think I got it working :). Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Yours is not a recursive function, a recursive function that calculates Golden Ratio would look like the one below.

```
private int MAX_COUNTER = 50;
private int count = 0;

public double ratio(double a, double b) {

    count++;

    double goldenRatio = b / a;

    if (count < MAX_COUNTER) {
        return ratio(b, a + b);
    }

    return goldenRatio;
}
```

NOTE: I put the counters because given that is a recursive function trying to find a number with infinite decimals, it will cause the JVM to go on StackOverflow :) , so we got to stop it sooner or later.

Comment: I don't think you should use number of iterations as the stop condition. Seeing as this is indeed a decimal number you'd usually like to reach a certain precision as the stop condition IMO.

Comment: Assaf, golden ratio is not just a decimal number, it is a limit, or even better, it is the limit of the ratio of consecutive Fibonacci numbers, so you cannot find all it's decimal numbers, I invite you to read this wikipedia link to understand better what the golden ratio is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio

Comment: The correct implementation would be whatever suits the requirements best. As you can see from the OP's test method he needed the answer to be correct to the 5th decimal place. Can you say how many iterations it would take to achieve that? Using number of iterations you would probably have to do too many iterations or not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion mainly means methods calling themself, meaning you should try something like that:

```
public double recursionMethod(int a, int b){
    int c = a+b;
    if(Math.abs(ratio(b,a)-ratio(c,b))< (double) 1/42)
        return ratio(c,b);
    else
        return recursionMethod(b,c);
}
```

1/42 is just your accuracy, you can implement any other breaking condition you like. Call this method in main with arguments (1,1).

Comment: But I don't want to have 2 methods such as ratio and recursionMethod. How can we implement those 2 methods into just one method and then call it from main?

Comment: Then implement the ratio method in this one, since it only returns (double) a/b with a test of proper arguments. (oh, you might want to change goldelRatio to double and make this cast. Else you will get only 1 or 0...)